# Editable table cells with App Inventor

Tags: javascript, android, app-inventor

I am building an app with **App Inventor**. I use a `Webviewer` to load a JavaScript code (see below) that displays, in a table, the content of a database stored in `TinyDB`.

So basically I have a table that looks like that:
[image]

I've tried to make the content of my table editable by adding this at the bottom of my script but without success: my table disappears.

```
 <script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").contentEditable = true;
}
  </script>
```

Also I've also seen this [page](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html). But I can't find way to implement this `.js` in my App Inventor app.

Any idea how to make this work?

```
<body>
  <div id="myTable"></div>
  <script>
    // get the table to display from the window.AppInventor object and split at new line
    var urlArray = window.AppInventor.getWebViewString().split("\n");

    var doc = document;
    var fragment = doc.createDocumentFragment();

    for(i=0;i<urlArray.length;i++){
      var tr = doc.createElement("tr");
      // split at comma
      var rowArray = urlArray[i].split("|");

      for(j=0;j<rowArray.length;j++){
        if ( i == 0) { var td = doc.createElement("th"); }
        else         { var td = doc.createElement("td"); }
        td.innerHTML = rowArray[j];
        tr.appendChild(td);
        fragment.appendChild(tr);
      }
    }
    var table = doc.createElement("table");
    table.appendChild(fragment);
    doc.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(table);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, this would be a nice enhancement of my [App Inventor and Dynamic Table Layout example](https://puravidaapps.com/table.php). If you find a solution to edit the table, afterwards you also will have to send the table back to App Inventor...

Comment: Yes, that's the second tricky part (I waited to have an answer to that question before asking that one!). I was hoping you would have known the solution Taifun, but apparently it's even more tricky than what I though.

Comment: I now spent some hours to enhance my example and made it "editable". The result you can find [here](https://puravidaapps.com/editable.php). Enjoy!